# how to separate clicks with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div like this...

```
<div class="user">
     <div class="info">
     .....
     </div>
     <div class="edit">
        Edit
     </div>
</div>
```

ON jquery I have something like this:

```
 $('user').click(function(){...});
 $('edit').click(function(){...});
```

If I click on "edit" both functions execute, I dont want that, if I click on "edit" only his function should happen.
Any ideas on how to separate this 2 functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Your selectors are wrong, you have to put `.` before class names like `.edit`, `.user`.

More here [`Class Selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

[`.stopPropagtion()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation)

You can use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) too like which will work for dynamically added elements too

```
$('body').on('click','.edit',function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Note**

You can replace `body` with any static parent that will always exist in dom. The closer the parent element the better it will perform.

Comment: Good note on the selectors. I'd advise to use [`$(document).on('click', '.edit', func)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) though, since it seems that the element appear more than once, possibly added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to correct your selectors. You need to have a `.` or `#` to signify an id or class in front of the name.

```
$(".edit").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```